# Dynamic property in planar vector in R

Tags: r, matlab, dynamic

I have to convert a code from *MATLAB* to *R*, but can't find the equivalent command in R. The *MATLAB* code is

```
if ~isfield(opt,'TolKKT'), opt.TolKKT = 0.001;
```

isfield in Matlab is used in order to determine if dynamic property exists in geographic or planar vector.

How can write it in R code? Assume that *opt* and *TolKKT* are defined in another of the code. My problem is the convertion of the ***isfield*** command

Comment: What data containers are you using in R (assuming it doesn't contain MATLAB-equivalent dynamic `struct`s)?